# Android tablayout selecting the last tab instead of first

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I need your help. I have a tablayout with tintable imageview and textview. I want to highlight the default selected tab which is the first one. 
This is my sample code:

```
TabLayout.Tab tab;
mTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
mViewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

mViewpager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
mViewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageScrollListener(mTabs));
mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);

// Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
    tab = mTabs.getTabAt(i);
    tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
}

mTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new MyOnTabSelectedListener());   
tab.select();
```

But it's selecting the last tab. Anyone here knows how to fix this? I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The `tab` is not within the scope, as it's being declared inside the `for-loop`.
When you want to select a tab you should do `mViewpager.setCurrentItem(indexOfItem)` instead.

Comment: @Darwind sorry I've updated my post.  tried mViewpager.setCurrentItem(0) but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646443/tab-custom-view-not-selected-in-tablayout?rq=1)

I added:

```
mTabs.getTabAt(1).select();    
mTabs.getTabAt(0).select();
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution. Instead if selecting the tab from the TabLayout you can do this with the ViewPager like so:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_menu_viewPager);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

// ViewPager mit TabLayout verknüpfen
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_menu_tabLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

See the post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762670/7318519

Answer (score 0):

You selected the last tab.
Take a look at your source code :)

```
TabLayout.Tab tab;
...
for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
    tab = mTabs.getTabAt(i);
}
...
tab.select();
```

`tab` is the last tab you will get with `getTabAt(int position)`.

So when you want to select the first tab this will help

```
maTabs.getTabAt(0).select();
```

Another (maybe better) solution is to turn the for loop into this

```
for (int i = mTabs.getTabCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tab = mTabs.getTabAt(i);
}
```

Then your "last" `tab` you are getting in this loop is the first tab in your `TabLayout`.

An working full example code looks like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b43882513f5d6923008a).

Comment: I followed this example: https://gist.github.com/tylerchesley/5d15d859be4f3ce31213 about the tintableImageview. But I even tried your updated code, but still (first tab) it's not highlighted. Whenever I click on other tabs, that's the only way to highlight the first tab.

Comment: I even tried setSelected(true) it highlights the 3 tabs but not the first one